# Take picture every 30ms with expo

Tags: android, expo

I am trying to take a picture every 30ms using expo app but its barely hitting 2fps. I assume its partly because of js timers not being accurate but this is well below my expectations. What alternates do I have? I have not tried recordAsync because I want to stream live images from expo app to a server. If I use recordAsync then I have to start and stop recording.

```
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

export default function App() {
  const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  if (!permission) {
    // Camera permissions are still loading
    return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
    // Camera permissions are not granted yet
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
        <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  async function startTakingPics() {
    console.log("Taking picture");
    setInterval( async ()=> {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync({base64: true});
      console.log(photo.base64.length)
    },50)
    
    // setType(current => (current === CameraType.back ? CameraType.front : CameraType.back));
  }

  const cameraReadyHook = async () => {
    console.log("camera  is ready");
    // const data = "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FStickerSmash-1962bf90-5c71-498b-a47a-f13359e194df/Camera/248d773b-58eb-4932-827d-057da6a5e2a3.jpg";
    // await FileSystem.deleteAsync(data);
    // const fileData = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(data);
    // console.log("File Data is: " +JSON.stringify(fileData));
    
    
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type} onCameraReady={()=>cameraReadyHook()} ref={cameraRef}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={startTakingPics}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Start taking pics</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    margin: 64,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: Not having tested it I would assume that it takes longer to take and process the image. Yes, timers aren't exact but taking essentially video via individual images seems extreme